# Model Structure for adding extra attributes to sub-class of a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, models, relationships

I have a rails model called "Contacts" which holds basic contact information for legal leads such as email, phone, name, etc. It looks like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :phone, :email, :city, :state, :zip_code
```

Depending on the type of contact they are, they need to have additional attributes which are different from each other.

I'd like behavior that would come from something like this:

```
class DisabilityContact < Contact 
    attr_accessible :employed, :medical_condition, :represented
```

But this is not possible because DisabilityContact uses the "Contact" table which does not contain those extra fields. I'd like advice on how to structure my models and relationships to be able to set these attributes doing something such as:

```
@contact = DisabilityContact.create
@contact.employed =  true
```

OR

```
@contact = DisabilityContact.create
@contact.special_attributes.employed = true
```

P.S. I'd prefer not to serialize any data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fields to the contact table anyway and use them only when needed.
Or you can have more than one table.

The article [Single Table Inheritance in Rails](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) might help you.

Comment: In that case I'd have to add about 50 extra columns to the contacts table, most of which will be empty for each record. Will this cause any foreseeable issues as the database grows?

Comment: I have same problem . Please notify me if you found the solution

Comment: @shyamkkhadka I ended up creating a column called :contact_data and storing all the additional serialized data in there.